# Geographic load balancing

Tags: load-balancing

At a company they currently have a typical webserver setup: one webserver and one database server.
Unfortunately there are often problems due to high load on the webserver and database so I was asked to configure load balancing with 2 webservers.

However someone asked me to place the second webserver on another company site (different country) to minimize the impact of network problems.

Is this a good idea? Wouldn't this cause more network problems due to redirections to a webserver so far away?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the details that your provided, I don't think there is enough information to say it is a good idea or not. It depends if the application is used by multiple countries or not plus other factors such as latency sensitiveness. Load balancing between 2 data centers might be a little more complex and expensive than Load balancing in the same data center.

**Some tricks you can do to increase performance**:

- Consider a Application Cache (such as [Varnish Cache Server](https://www.cloudflare.com/)): This shall decrease the load towards your web servers, namely the static content.

**Low complexity Load balancing**:

- Add a new DNS "A record" for your web site pointing to a second web server. E.g: www.mysite.com will resolve on round-robin basis to webserver1 and webserver2 - Be careful how your web application handles sessions. If you have multiple DB servers you need to have all DB syncing with each other.

**Medium complexity Load balancing**:

- Consider an Load balancer appliance such as F5 sitting before the web clusters.
- Consider a CDN service such as: [Incapsula](http://www.incapsula.com/load-balancing/), [Akamai](http://www.akamai.com/html/solutions/global-traffic-management.html) or [CloudFlare](https://www.cloudflare.com/)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you still have only one database, the most important question to ask is, how much will the remote webserver depend on the database?

If everything the webserver does will depend on communicating with a database in another location, then you will have increased exposure in case of network problems. If you have pages needing multiple database queries, those will be slower to render due to additional network roundtrips between webserver and database.

Replicating the database would be an option. But preserving consistency across replicated databases is very challenging. (To handle a case of one replica failing in an arbitrary way, you need at least four replicas. Any solution claiming to achieve this with fewer replicas has been making assumptions about how failures behave, and once failures do not live up to those assumptions, the system breaks down.)

If replicating the database isn't practical for you, and the webserver cannot do anything meaningful without the database, the configuration I would recommend for maximum redundancy is the following:

Use three servers, each of which is equipped with two network interfaces. One will be the database, the other two will be webservers. Each webserver gets connected directly to the database with an Ethernet cable. Not even a switch will be put between them, such that as long as both webserver and database are up, they can communicate with each other.

Those two Ethernet cables occupies most of the interfaces. You are left with one available interface on each webserver. Those remaining interfaces are connected to two independent network providers. In my experience the connection to the network provider is the least reliable part of the setup and hence the most important part to have redundancy on, and the setup I described here can make that part redundant without replicating the database to multiple servers. Even if one of the providers mess up BGP to the point that their entire AS drops off the internet, you site remains available through the other webserver.

Comment: It is a possibility to replicate the DB. But if the argument for running two webservers on different company sites and not in one datacenter is "minimizing the impact of network problems", is it still a good idea? If the two webservers are geologically separated, will this minimize the impact on the network?

Comment: @chiodos You haven't told us how much of the traffic can be handled without communicating with the database.

Comment: Every webpage need communication with the database. So 100% of web traffic

Comment: @chiodos In that case you will decrease reliability by putting the secondary webserver in a different location, because the secondary webserver will be unusable unless both sites are up. There may be another option though, I'll expand the answer.